# What is a word to describe blatant praise by a shill?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a word to describe an article published in a newspaper that's written by a shill. Basically a word that describes the article as blatant over the top praise without perspective. I know 'advertorial' might work but I'm looking for an adjective that describes a panegyric that isn't genuine.

Comment: Even asskissery, perhaps.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Meretricious**, meaning attractive in a way that is false or that lacks integrity (an extension of the older meaning of the word, meaning "relating to prostitution").

Comment: I don't think this is quite on the mark. I would think something like *sycophantic* would be closer to the truth.

Comment: Meretricious, and a Happy New Year!

Comment: @Robusto - I'm not sure I think it's better, but "sycophantic" is a reasonable alternative. If you think it's better than the currently accepted answer, why bury it in a comment instead of suggesting it as an answer?

Answer (score 18):

**Astroturfing** is often used for the online version of this, maybe for paper newspapers as well. Astroturf is a brand of artificial grass, so this is an artificial grassroots article.

> Astroturfing is the practice of masking the sponsors of a message (e.g. political, advertising, religious or public relations) to make it appear as though it originates from grassroots participant(s). Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing)

Answer (score 11):

[Advertorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertorial) is what I call them. Or [puff pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puff_piece#Puff_piece).

Answer (score 7):

That sounds like your typical **plug**.

Answer (score 3):

Popular recently, and with a mildly humorous connotation (or at least origin), is "astroturfing."  It's a play on "grassroots" - instead of getting actual *sua sponte* testimonials or support, you plant fake support.  Wikipedia puts the origin back to 1985, but I first saw it in the IEEE Spectrum a couple of years ago. http://spectrum.ieee.org/geek-life/tools-toys/the-language-of-online-life

Answer (score 2):

"Propaganda" or simply "Marketing".

Answer (score 2):

I'd call it a "promotional piece".  It has the intended meaning of blatantly biased advertising and the added advantage of people knowing what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm fond of the noun 'puffery'. If you prefer an adjective, perhaps 'effusive'.

Comment: _Effusive_ does not imply falsehood, I can be completely impartial and still offer effusive praise.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has been debating the issue and was describing it as "paid advocacy."  I'd suggest that term or "paid advocate."

Answer (score 1):

**"Sockpuppeting"** would fit perfectly, but only in cases where the (false) praise is being given at the direct direction of the praisee.

Comment: IMO, sockpuppeting is more like the praise being written by the "praisee" pseudonymously.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Graham calls that kind of subtle PR article [a submarine](http://www.paulgraham.com/submarine.html). I haven't heard that term used widely outside the tech-heavy crowd that reads his essays though.

Comment: The linked article uses "submarine" as a description for the whole PR industry ("lurking beneath the news").  I don't see it used for a specific kind of planted article.

Comment: True, I guess I've just read the term being used that way in forum comments.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 100% spot-on, but it's at least worth considering:

*obsequious* - Excessively deferential to authority

*"The writer's praise of his editor was nakedly obsequious."*

Answer (score -1):

You could also consider *claptrap*, which refers to pretentious but insincere or empty language.

Answer (score -2):

You might also consider *rhetorical*:

> [*rhetoric*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetoric) : language that is intended to influence people and that may not be honest or reasonable